# echo inserted session(username) variable

Tags: php, session, insert, userid

session user id: `$_SESSION['uid']`

session username: `$_SESSION['username']`

variable: `$creator = $_SESSION['uid'];`

query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO posts (category_id, title, content, source, creator, date) 
        VALUES ('1', '".$title."', '".$content."', '".$src."', '".$creator."', now())";
```

**problem:** When I `echo $row['creator']` the username doesnt appear in letters rather in numbers(0,1).

What I want: **Creator: David**

What it shows: **Creator: 1**

thnx!

Comment: echo $row['creator'], but what is assigned to $row?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what the actual values of your session variables it *looks* like you are assigning the wrong session variable to $creator. The `uid` array key indicates a numerical value. You are probably supposed to assigning `$_SESSION['username']` to `$creator` instead:

```
$creator = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Comment: What is the data type of the `creator column in your db?

Comment: data type is int(11), should I maybe change it to varchar? But then i wont be able to identify the creator? @JohnConde

Comment: If it is an int then it makes sense why you see what you see. You'll need to find a way to correlate that number to the user. This is usually done using a SQL JOIN.

Comment: ok, so how do I join the username with the userid using the join function? Kinda new in this...thnx

Comment: SELECT users.userid
FROM users
INNER JOIN posts
ON posts.creator;    something like this??